# ClassNotFoundException when load class with Class.forName

Tags: java, exception, classloader

When I using the `Class.forName` to load a class, there is an exception

> ClassNotFoundException

Do you know what may be reason?

```
Class<?> cl;
try {
    cl = Class.forName("com.qti.server.power.ShutdownOem");
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    Log.d("localdebug", "testLoadClass ClassNotFoundException com.qti.server.power.ShutdownOem");
}
```

Comment: Some code would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

[Class.forName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) only accepts `fully-qualified names`, secondly class may not be present at the time of loading into `classloaders`

refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749741/though-my-class-was-loaded-class-forname-throws-classnotfoundexception) for more

Comment: Yes, I used the packagename+classname as the inputed name for Class.forName(). Do you think that could be ok?

Comment: @user3236879 should be `packageName.className`

Comment: Yes. I used packageName.className.

Comment: @user3236879 then it means class is not present at runtime in classpath.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassNotFoundException` occurs when class loader could not find the required class in class path.

Check your class path and add the class in the classpath. The class name must be fully qualified (with packages).

Comment: I have checked. There is no problem with the class path.

Comment: The problem is with the class loader. The class loader doesn't see you class path. Check it (for example in the Manifest.mf if it is a jar or the WEB-INF/lib directory)

Comment: @user3236879 You asked what the exception means, and you got an answer. If you want help troubleshooting your program, you should post your code. Be sure to include the specific string that you're passing to `Class.forname()`.